# Collatz conjecture: Count how many have the length 111

Tags: java, collatz

So my question is about the collatz conjecture. The task is that I have to write a code which counts the length of steps of each conjecture. For example `2 = 2/2 = 1` is one step.

Now I need to know how many start numbers between 1 and 10000 have 111+ steps. I get 54 on my code but I don't have any sources wether its right or wrong.

`anzahl` should be the counter of how many numbers have 111 steps and `laenge` is the length of each number:

```
public class Collertz {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        int max = 111;
        int anzahl = 0;
        int laenge = 0;

        for(int i=0; i<=10000;i++) {
            for (int j = i; i>1; i++) {
                if (j%2 == 0) {
                    j = j/2;
                    laenge++;
                }
                else {
                    j = 3*j+1;
                    laenge++;
                }
            }
            if (laenge >= max) {
                anzahl++;
            }
        }
        System.out.println(anzahl);
    }
}
```

Comment: And what exactly are you now asking?

Comment: You count also sequences with a length greater than 111, so your result is probably wrong, unless there is no such sequence below 10000.

Comment: You increment laenge in the if-branch, as well as in the else branch. You don't reset laenge. You could move the test for laenge == max inside the for loop, and break it, if reached, since you aren't using larger iterations for anything.

Answer (score 0):

I see two problems with your code, one major and one minor.  The major problem is that you test and increment `i` in the `for` statement of your second loop.  Should you not be testing j and not incrementing anything?  I would have used a `while` loop myself.  The small problem is that your first loop starts with 0 rather than 1.  But this should not impact your results.

Answer (score 0):

Your code suffers from the bad habit to write everything in the main method.

You should at least write a (pure) function that gives you the length of the sequence for some argument. Then a simple for loop is enough to find out how many function values fit your criteria.

But since you prefer to write everything in one go, you promptly introduced a severe error. Just think about what the variable `laenge` gives you? What is its intended purpose? And does it fulfil that purpose or should it rather read `sumOfLengths`.

Answer (score 0):

Here are the issues resolved, as mentioned in my comment:

```
static int collatz (int max) {
    int anzahl = 0;
    for(int i=1; i<=10000; ++i) {
        for (int j = i, laenge=0; j>1; laenge++) {
            if (j % 2 == 0) 
                j /= 2;
            else 
                j = 3*j+1;
            if (laenge == max) {
                anzahl++;
                break;
            }
        }
    }
    System.out.println(anzahl);
    return anzahl;
}
collatz (111);
```

- laenge++ is performed in every branch of the if statement.
- laenge is reset for every new number.
- we break the inner for-loop when reaching anzahl.
- i++ in the inner loop was wrong.
- it's j which needs to stay above 1 to proceed, not i

I didn't look up, what the rules for the collatz-condingsbums are, it sounded reasonable. :)